# How to insert into SQLliteDatabase android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a problem when I try to insert some data into an SQLliteDatabase that I created in android.

Below is my code to create the Database which i created in a class called SQLlitenew:

```
public class SQLlitenew{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID="id";
    public static final String KEY_PRODUCTNAME="ProductName";
    public static final String KEY_PRODUCTTYPE="ProductType";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION="place";
    public static final String KEY_WORKER="worker";
    public static final String KEY_QUESTION1="Question1";
    public static final String KEY_QUESTION2="Question2";
    public static final String KEY_QUESTION3="Question3";
    public static final String KEY_QUESTION4="Question4";
    public static final String KEY_QUESTION5="Question5";
    public static final String KEY_TIME="time";
    public static final String KEY_UPLOADED="uploaded"; 
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL="emailAdd";
    public static final String TAG="DBAdapter"; // This is for logging information e.g LOG.d

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="NOID";
    private final static String DATABASE_TABLE="session";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (id INT(11) primary key autoincrement, " +
            "ProductName VARCHAR, ProductType VARCHAR, place INT(5), worker VARCHAR, " +
            "Question1 VARCHAR, Question2 VARCHAR, Question3 VARCHAR, Question4 VARCHAR, Question5 VARCHAR, " +
            "time long, uploaded INT(1), emailAdd VARCHAR );";


    //create instant of DBhelper class
    private DBHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //First create the database table
            try{
            ourDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            Log.w(DATABASE_CREATE,"successssssssssssssss!");

            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w(DATABASE_CREATE,"FFFAAAAIIIIIILLLLLLEEEDDDDDDDDDDDD!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //----always move the Data before Deleting the Data----->
            Log.w(TAG, "This is will delete the previous data which will make you lose all information from the" +oldVersion + "and will create a new database to the " + newVersion);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    //set up public contructor
    public SQLlitenew(Context c){
        this.ourContext = c;
        ourHelper = new DBHelper(c);

    }

    public long insertRecord(String productName,  String productType, String place, String name, String ans1, String ans2, String ans3, String firstChoice, String secondChoice, long time, int uploaded, String email){

        //writing stuff into db
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();

        content.put(KEY_PRODUCTNAME, productName);
        content.put(KEY_PRODUCTTYPE, productType);
        content.put(KEY_LOCATION, place);
        content.put(KEY_WORKER, name);
        content.put( KEY_QUESTION1, ans1);
        content.put( KEY_QUESTION2, ans2);
        content.put( KEY_QUESTION3, ans3);
        content.put( KEY_QUESTION4, firstChoice);
        content.put( KEY_QUESTION5, secondChoice);
        content.put(KEY_TIME, time);
        content.put( KEY_UPLOADED, uploaded);
        content.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);      


        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, content);

    }
    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the code within a separate class where I am calling the function to insert data:

```
SQLlitenew entry = new SQLlitenew(this);
entry.open();
entry.insertRecord(product, productType, place, name, ans1, ans2, ans3, firstChoice, secondChoice, time, uploaded, email);
entry.close();
```

The problem is that when ever I attempt the insert, it brings this error:

```
12-18 13:08:45.029: I/Database(4282): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: session
12-18 13:08:45.044: E/Database(4282): Error inserting time=1355864924948 ProductType=Food Question5=Fresh & Clean Scents i.e nourishing milk & honey that hydrates and protects
12-18 13:08:45.044: E/Database(4282):  uploaded=0 Question4=Chip resistant nail polish 
12-18 13:08:45.044: E/Database(4282):  worker=ttt Question3=YES ProductName=tyyyy Question2=African American Question1=Under 25 place=56677 emailAdd=t@n.com
12-18 13:08:45.044: E/Database(4282): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: session: , while compiling: INSERT INTO session(time, ProductType, Question5, uploaded, Question4, worker, Question3, ProductName, Question2, Question1, place, emailAdd) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

New Errors on raising the database_version to 3.

```
12-18 14:00:38.794: I/Database(4384): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
12-18 14:00:38.794: E/Database(4384): Failure 1 (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) on 0x279960 when preparing 'create table if not exists session (id INT(11) primary key autoincrement, ProductName VARCHAR, ProductType VARCHAR, place INT(5), worker VARCHAR, Question1 VARCHAR, Question2 VARCHAR, Question3 VARCHAR, Question4 VARCHAR, Question5 VARCHAR, time long, uploaded INT(1), emailAdd VARCHAR );'.
12-18 14:00:38.802: W/System.err(4384): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: create table if not exists session (id INT(11) primary key autoincrement, ProductName VARCHAR, ProductType VARCHAR, place INT(5), worker VARCHAR, Question1 VARCHAR, Question2 VARCHAR, Question3 VARCHAR, Question4 VARCHAR, Question5 VARCHAR, time long, uploaded INT(1), emailAdd VARCHAR );
```

I can't figure it out and it's been driving me crazy! Thanks for your time looking over this question.

Comment: Did you rename your table? If so, did you remember to change the db version in order to delete / recreate? Is DATABASE_TABLE value "session"?

Comment: yes DATABASE_TABLE is  = "session". That's the only time i named the table. The database_version = 2

Comment: Hmm, what you posted looks fine. Please post your SQLiteOpenHelper subclass' `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` methods.

Comment: Ok I will edit it to add that.

Comment: I just decided to put most of the SQLlitenew class. Hopefully it helps. Thanks for looking over this.

Comment: Unless `open()` does something out of the ordinary, I don't see why this shouldn't work... Raise `DATABASE_VERSION` to 3 and post your Logcat warnings (at the least you should see a success or failure message).

Comment: Nice call Sam, its bring up some error warnings about auto-increment, which doesn't make sense because id is set to integer. Check my Edit, i'll post it in a few seconds.

Comment: Not that it is necessarily cause of the problem but `"DROP TABLE IF EXIST "` - that should be `...EXISTS`

Answer (score 2):

For Android your `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` should be named `_id` and according to the error you need to use `INTEGER` not `INT(11)`. The proper syntax is:

```
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
```

`AUTOINCREMENT` and `NOT NULL` are implied. You can add them if you want but they are "syntactic sugar".

Comment: lovely. Thanks. Men its the little things that get you all the freaking time! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, it is. Make sure you address Squonk's comment above as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to execute your code.

The problem is that the database creation `ourDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);`
 fails because of

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: , while compiling:

You need to declare id as  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, instead of INT(11)

Given the failure of the table creation, subsequent inserts wont work.